# Set UIButton title to selected table cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a `UITableView` loading a different array when clicking on different buttons. What I want is to update the `UIButton` titles to the selected table cell. So for example: the user has selected table row 4 which has the text "April 2013". The button updates its title to "April 2013". **This is working.** Now, the user switches between TableView by clicking on a button (loading new data in the SAME array). The `UITableView` with table row 4 named "April 2013" updates its fields using the same array and the field previously selected is still preserved but now with different data. Yet the UIButton title is still showing "April 2013", I want to change it so that when clicking on the button and changing the data of the array, the button title changes aswell.

**DidSelectRowAtIndexPath:**

```
if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dateSpecifiedButtonText:)]) 
{
    [self.delegate dateSpecifiedButtonText:selCell.textLabel.text];
}
```

**ViewController.m:**

```
- (void)dateSpecifiedButtonText:strText2 
{
   [self.dateSpecifiedButton setTitle:strText2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

In short: How do I update a `UIButton` title to show a current selected table cell.

I hope you understand the question.

Comment: Reset all the button title whenever you are switching between tableView's.

Comment: I would rather suggest, instead of saving data, save index, ie save 4th row, and when you show new data just highlight the row 4.So it will automatically show 4th row as highlighted.

Comment: And how would I execute these methods?

Comment: Not sure of the rest of your code but it sounds to me you will have to write a method that gets executed when new data is loaded into your array and updates your button text. Without such a method, your button text will not update automatically.

Comment: When you load the new data, what should the button text be, and should the previously selected row stay selected?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the button title based on the contents of the cell, try setting the title based on the contents of the array:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *titleToUse = [arrayWithData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dateSpecifiedButtonText:)]) 
{
    [self.delegate dateSpecifiedButtonText:titleToUse];
}

}
```