# Changing UIButton title to selected table cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I want to change a `UIButton` text to the selected cell in a `UITableView`. Normally this would be done like this.

**TableView.m**:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(ButtonText:)]) {
    [self.delegate ButtonText:selCell.textLabel.text];
  }
}
```

**ViewController.m**:

```
- (void)dateSpecifiedButtonText:strText2 
{
    [self.dateSpecifiedButton setTitle:strText2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
}
```

This is working when I select the cell but what I want is to change the button to the cell when you click on another button. So I need to rewrite this method without using `didSelectRowAtIndex` but I have no idea how.

Comment: this another buttopn lies in where? the same cell?

Comment: are you both Classmates??? same question posted few minutes back!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16895907/set-uibutton-title-to-selected-table-cell

Comment: I cannot understand your question...Could you explain better? Thanks.

Comment: All the buttons are located and defined in ViewController.h/m. @flexaddicted: Im trying to update the text of a UIButton to the selected text in a tableview. I got this working by using DidSelectRowAtIndex but I want it to update when I select another button and not a tablerow.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the indexPath of the cell in which button is

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForIndexPath:indexPath];
```

If you have just added button to contentView of cell give a unique tag to the button

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewForTag:55];
```

Now you have the instance of button, set the text to it.